# Columns to Rows in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have the following table structure in Hive,

```
Date         ID        x1         x1_value      x2         x2_value
2018-09-17    1        a             10          b            20
2018-09-17    2        b             20          c            30
```

I want to convert this to ,

```
Date         ID        x         x_value     
2018-09-17    1        a             10      
2018-09-17    1        b             20         
2018-09-17    2        b             20      
2018-09-17    2        c             30
```

I want to do this Hive. Can anybody please give idea to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with an inline `array` of `struct`s in conjunction with `lateral view`.

```
select date,id,x,x_value
from tbl
lateral view inline(array(struct(x1,x1_value),struct(x2,x2_value))) t as x,x_value
```